# Populate missing mongoose schema fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Let's say I have a simple mongoose Schema

```
mySchema = new Schema({
    field1: {
      type: String,
   },
field2: {
      type: String,
   },
field3: {
      type: String,
   },
})
```

Depending on the business logic inside the application, not all fields will be saved into the database, so I may have records of mySchema in which field1 is missing, for example.

Now in a specific scenario, when I fetch mySchema from the database, I need to populate all missing fields with default values (or any value I determine), for example, if I fetch mySchema and it contains field2 and field3, I would need to add field1 with an empty string as a value.

What could be the best approach for that?

I tried adding manually the properties after fetching mySchema, however, it was too overwhelming because I needed to use **hasOwnProperty** for all properties and we have some big schemas inside the application

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mongoose` default values:

```
field1: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
   }
```

That way, `mongoose` will assign a default value to that field if that value doesn't exists on the database